# Facebook login on my website works fine in html page but how can i convert the same into angular js code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook-login

Im new to angular js.My code works fine with normal html file having logic in script tags but when trying to segregate the code by using angular js Im getting errors.I had referred many articles but still I could not implement it successfully.
Here is my code that works fine in normal html file. 
code:

```
<body ng-view="">

<button id="loginBtn">Facebook Login</button>
<button id="logoutBtn">Facebook Logout</button>

<div id="response"></div>
<div
    class="fb-like"
    data-share="true"
    data-width="450"
    data-show-faces="true">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        //SDK loaded, initialize it
        FB.init({
            appId: '*******',
            xfbml: true,
            version: 'v2.3'
        });

        //check user session and refresh it
        FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                //user is authorized
                document.getElementById('loginBtn').style.display = 'none';
                getUserData();
            } else {
                //user is not authorized
            }
        });
    };
    function getUserData() {
        FB.api('/me', function (response) {
            document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = 'Hello ' + response.name;
        });
    }

    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        //SDK loaded, initialize it
        FB.init({
            appId: '****',
            xfbml: true,
            version: 'v2.3'
        });

        //check user session and refresh it
        FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                //user is authorized
                document.getElementById('loginBtn').style.display = 'none';
                getUserData();
            } else {
                //user is not authorized
            }
        });
    };

    //load the JavaScript SDK
    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    //add event listener to login button
    document.getElementById('loginBtn').addEventListener('click', function () {
        //do the login
        FB.login(function (response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                //user just authorized your app
                document.getElementById('loginBtn').style.display = 'none';
                getUserData();
            }
        }, { scope: 'email,public_profile', return_scopes: true });
    }, false);
</script></body>
```

Now im unable to convert the same code into angular js code.Can anyone please help me out.

Comment: You have to create an angular directive for this https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: I have created a ng-view div in main html and then through ngroute im referring to html page having a login button. so how can i include this script tag code in directive. can you help me with some example

Comment: what have you tried so far with angular? no offense, but this i no place to get code for free just because you did not learn angular yet. just learn the basics and soon it will be no problem at all for you to create a simple angular service for the facebook stuff. i would suggest using a service, not a directive, btw.

Comment: ya i was able to do it. Thanks.